# How to define static index for tabPanel

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using `PrimeNG tabView` component to display steps, let's say i have 3 steps **[1,2,3]**, and i'm using `handleTabViewChange(e)` to load data with the index of the step

The corresponding index is **[0,1,2]**, step 2 is displayed with a condition, when it's not displayed i have 2 steps **[1,3]** with index **[0,1]**, so the index of step 3 changes to **[1]** :

Is there a way to set a static index for each tab, so when step 2 is not displayed the index of step 3 stays **[2]**:

```
<p-tabView (onChange)="handleTabViewChange($event)">
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 1" >

    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 2" *ngIf="false" >
        
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 3" >
        
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

**handleTabViewChange(e):**

```
  data: any[];

  handleTabViewChange(e) {    
    var step= e.index + 1;
    this.data = this.loadData(step);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe an option to use [hidden]="true" instead of the *ngIf ?

Comment: [hidden]="true" works, but it hides the content of tabPanel, and not the tabPanel

Comment: Why do you need the index of step 3 to be 2? What's wrong with it becoming 1?

Comment: beacause i'm loading data by the step, and the step = index +1, so if the index of step 3 becomes 1, then if i change tabPanel to step 3 it will load data of step 2 (1+1)

Comment: Idea: modify `handleTabViewChange` so that it knows that the index has changed and requests the data for step 3 when presented with index of 1

Comment: i have 10 steps (i put 3 in question just to be clear), and each step will be shown by user's role, so i can't treat each case, i wanna make it clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a directive which adds a static `index` property to the panels, and by using `ViewChildren` to enumerate the rendered panels:

Directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'p-tabPanel'
})
export class MyTabPanelDirective {
  @Input() index: number;

  constructor() {}
}
```

The tab view in your template should look something like this:

```html
<p-tabView (onChange)="handleTabViewChange($event)">
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 1" [index]="0">

    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 2" [index]="1" *ngIf="false" >
        
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Step 3" [index]="2" >
        
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

And finally your component can handle the `onChange` like this:

```js
  @ViewChildren(MyTabPanelDirective) panels: QueryList<MyTabPanelDirective>;

  handleTabViewChange(e) {
    const step = this.panels.get(e.index + 1).index;
    this.data = this.loadData(step);
  }
```

The way this works is that the event argument includes the index of the panel in the DOM, and this matches the view children query list (with a caveat, see below). Then in the event handler we take the DOM index, add 1, and extract the static index from the directive.

**CAVEAT 1** if you manipulate the tab panels in code, by adding or removing or reordering them, then the query list order might not match the DOM order.

**CAVEAT 2** if you have two tab views in the same template, you have to change this a bit.

### Solution for caveat #2

#### Multiple tab views

Use a service provided by the tab view (so each tab view has its own instance) - and inject it into the panels. Every panel will then register itself with the service, and this will happen according to the order of the DOM (at least initially, see caveat #1).

Then in the event handler, query the tab view's service for the panel by index.

Service:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TabRepoService {
  panels: MyTabPanelDirective[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  addPanel(panel: MyTabPanelDirective) {
    this.panels.push(panel);
  }
}
```

The tab view directive attaches to all tab views and creates a service instance for itself and its children (the panels):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'p-tabView',
  exportAs: 'myTabView',

  // This means there will be a separate instance per tab view
  providers: [TabRepoService] 
})
export class MyTabViewDirective {
  constructor(public repo: TabRepoService) {}

  getPanelAtIndex(i: number) {
    return this.repo.panels[i];
  }
}
```

Next, modify the panel directive to use this service to register themselves:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'p-tabPanel',
})
export class MyTabPanelDirective {
  @Input() index: number;

  constructor(private repo: TabRepoService) {
    repo.addPanel(this);
  }
}
```

The html usage:

```html
<p-tabView #tab1="myTabView" (onChange)="handleTabViewChange($event, tab1)">
  <p-tabPanel header="Header 1" [index]="0">
    Content 1
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Header 2" [index]="1" *ngIf="false">
    Content 2
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Header 3" [index]="2">
    Content 3
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Note that we pass the tab view directive to the event handler, so that it can query it for it's child by index.

And finally the event handler:

```js
  handleTabViewChange(e, t: MyTabViewDirective) {
    const step = t.getPanelAtIndex(e.index).index;
    this.data = this.loadData(step);
  }
```

Note: In this solution `ViewChildren` is not required.

Example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdn1th?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: it works, i just had to change: this.panels.get(e.index + 1).index to  this.panels.get(e.index).index + 1

Comment: That can't be right you want the next DOM panel's index so the +1 is to the query list index. But whatever works :)